# How to check python asycio.socket data order

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-sockets

I am making a socket client with python asyncio.

When connected to the server, it continues to receive the data size initially, and receives the data as much as the size.

However, sometimes the client receives the original data rather than the size of the original data, which is the first data to be received.

So, I am trying to write using asyncio.Queue,
I can't figure out how to implement it and put data into the queue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Send part

```
  while True:
    # type(data) - np.ndarray  
    str_data = base64.b64encode(data)
    length = str(len(str_data))
    writer.write(length.encode('utf-8').ljust(64))
    await writer.drain()
    writer.write(str_data)
    await writer.drain()
```

Receive part

```
async def socket_handler(self, reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
  while True:
    try:
      data: bytes = await reader.read(64)
      try:
          mes = int(data.decode())
      except ValueError:
          print('invalid data skip')
          await reader.read(-1)
          continue
      data: bytes = await reader.read(mes)
      self.data = deepcopy(data)
```

Comment: First of all, you have an unmatched try: in your receive part.  You asked about Queue, but your problem appears to be that the send part is an infinite loop and the receive part connects to it randomly (in an unsynchronized manner).  Sometimes the receive part gets the length first and sometimes the data.  Is that a correct description of the problem?  In that case, I don't know why you're asking about a Queue.  I don't see how that will help you.  And why doesn't the try:except: block in your code already solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`asyncio.readexactly`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=drain#asyncio.StreamReader.readexactly) to ensure how many bytes are read.

I suggest closing the socket when error occur because it is unlikely to recover from non-aligned data stream.

```py
async def socket_handler(self, reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
    while True:
        data: bytes = await reader.readexactly(64)
        try:
            mes = int(data.decode())
        except ValueError:
            writer.close()
            return
            # print('invalid data skip')
            # await reader.read(-1)
            # continue
        try:
            data: bytes = await reader.readexactly(mes)
        except asyncio.IncompleteReadError:
            writer.close()
            return
        self.data = deepcopy(data)
```

Moreover,

- [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module can pack length in bytes.
- `numpy.array` can be sent directly using `memoryview`

```py
async def sender():
    while True:
        # type(data) - np.ndarray
        mv = memoryview(data)
        length = len(mv)
        writer.write(struct.pack('!Q', length))
        await writer.drain()
        writer.write(mv)
        await writer.drain()


async def socket_handler(self, reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
    while True:
        try:
            length, = struct.unpack('!Q', await reader.readexactly(8))
            data = await reader.readexactly(length)
        except asyncio.IncompleteReadError:
            writer.close()
            return

        # change dtype to the actual one
        # reshape is probably needed
        array = np.from_buffer(data, dtype=np.float64)
```